# Unwanted Insets in fullpage view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to create a paginated collection view

this is how it looks like now

there is some inset between the cells

However, I set

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width,
                      [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height);
}
```

I thought that will make the cells in the size of the screen

How can I remove the insets (from all sides)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(1) Is this really a candidate for a collection view? It looks more like a scroll view or a page view. You might want to reconsider your architecture here.

(2) Your `applicationFrame` is a very risky strategy; there are much better ways to say "the same size as the screen" or "the same size as the root view". Nevertheless, the `applicationFrame` size looks to me like it's working perfectly. The problem is not the *size* but the *origin* of these cells. As you say, there's an inset between them. That's a feature of the layout which is responsible for positioning them. You have to tell it what spacing you want.